# Area of a parametric surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

> Given the parametric surface $\Phi(\rho,\theta)=(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,\theta)$, $\rho\in]0,1]$, $\theta\in[0,4\pi]$ find its area.

This is a kind of exercise i might find in my multivariable calculus exam.

*I'm struggling to find a way to solve it because there's no resolution method mentioned in the study material my prof gave me for this kind of exercise*.

I guess i need to do some sort of integration to solve this, but i don't know which one to look up for. I think an example could help me understand.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter no, this topic has not been treated at lesson yet, the fact is that i'm going ahead with the program because i have little time to prepare before the exam, anyway if you told me what to look up i'd be very grateful

Comment: See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I'm curious as to why you think this is not doable at all. I'm going to give it a shot in a little bit to maybe see for myself

Comment: Either this has been treated in the course, or your prof assumed you are able to look up the (standard) formula in a suitable resource. It is not expected that you find (and prove) this formula yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call ${\bf r}(\rho,\theta) = \rho\cos\theta \hat{x}+ \rho\sin\theta\hat{y} + \theta\hat{z}$, and define the vectors

\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf r}_\rho &=& \frac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial \rho} = \cos\theta\hat{x} + \sin\theta\hat{y} \\
{\bf r}_\theta &=& \frac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial \theta} = -\rho\sin\theta\hat{x} + \rho\cos\theta\hat{y} + \hat{z}
\end{eqnarray}

All you need to do now is to calculate $|{\bf r}_\rho\times {\bf r}_\theta|$, and integrate

$$
\int_0^1{\rm d}\rho\int_0^{4\pi}{\rm d}\theta  ~|{\bf r}_\rho\times {\bf r}_\theta|
$$